# Request sensitive data from a remote server in the correct way

Tags: jquery, json, html

I'm developing a mobile app which works against a remote server.

On my app, each of my users has user data which includes some sensitive data. (stored in a db)
My main question is, once my user logs/signup to my app, I'd like to get the user's data from the server in a secure way. Currently, I'm returning JSON data by using simple GET requests, such as /getuser/id. This is clearly not a good way to return the sensitive data since it's open to anyone.

Simple flow to consider:
User is logged, get user data from server, save data on user's device.

1. Could you please shed some light about this issue?
2. How would you get the data right and in a secure way?
3. Do i need to create an entire logic which makes it secure?
4. Should I use POST requests?

Comment: ssl + session management. Get requests are appropriate since you are getting data not posting data. The security should revolve around the user being logged in, and whether or not the user is authorized to view said data.

Comment: Would it be wrong to use POST to get the data? what about requests per session or something like that?

Comment: using POST instead of GET to get data would work (assuming your api supports it), but post isn't any more secure than get. It doesn't hide anything. Whether or not it's right or wrong is debatable. requests per session has nothing to do with security and can be bypassed by simply opening up a new session (such as clearing cookies).

Comment: @KevinB it doesn't hide anything on the wire, true, but `POST` does provide a screen against browser history sniffing, if there are any session tokens exposed in the URL.

Comment: what about api keys for each GET. the key can work like a user authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some suggestions for you,

```
 (1) Use secure encryption/decryption algorithms like AES-256 with user credentials based cryptographic key for sensitive data transmission in client server architecture.  
For more security you can use public key algorithm (like RSA-1024) to exchange symmetric key(Here AES) between client server. 


        1. @SERVER -----> generate Public-Private Key(RSA) ---> Send public key to Client.<br/>
        2. @CLIENT------> generate unique AES key using hash(username+passwd+salt)----> Encrypt Hash Value using RSA public key ---> Send Encrypt value to SERVER<br/>
        3. @SERVER------> decrypt  Encrpted AES Key using private key(RSA). Now SERVER have got AES key & CLIENT have it already.<br/>
        4. SERVER <------AES Encryption/Decryption----> CLIENT<br/>

     (2) Use SSL/TLS protocol for transport layer security.

     (3)  Use POST method for improved security.

     (4)  Code obfuscation & jumble algorithms can be applied for secure key generation to avoid reverse engineering attacks upto a level.
```